# Dynamical systems and differential equations reviews/surveys?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, soft-question, dynamical-systems

I would be very glad if someone could point me to modern reviews/surveys on these topics.
To be concrete, I'll provide some examples:

- *S. Smale*,  [Differentiable dynamical systems](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1967-73-06/S0002-9904-1967-11798-1/)
- *D. V. Anosov*, [On the development of the theory of dynamical systems during the past quarter century](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9780511614156&cid=CBO9780511614156A011)

So, I'm looking for texts that talk about current development of theory, milestone ideas, possible directions and open questions.

As I've already said, my topics of interest are dynamical systems and differential equations (primarily ODE). But other texts will be interesting too if their topics are closely related to these; e.g. PDEs, chaotic dynamics, symbolic dynamics, Hamiltonian systems, etc.

So, thanks in advance!

**LATER ADDITIONS:**

If no one doesn't mind, I would like to add from time to time interesting findings to this list.

- *P. Holmes*, [Ninety plus thirty years of nonlinear dynamics: less is more and more is different](http://chaosbook.org/library/HolmesNonlHist05.pdf)
- *M. Golubitskiy, I. Stewart*, [Recent Advances in Symmetric and Network Dynamics](http://people.mbi.ohio-state.edu/golubitsky.4/reprintweb-0.5/output/papers/periodic_survey_3_2_15b.pdf)
- *P. Ashwin, S. Coombes, R. Nicks*, [Mathematical frameworks for oscillatory network dynamics in neuroscience](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.05828v1.pdf)
- *M. Viana*, [Dynamical Systems: Moving into the Next Century](http://preprint.impa.br/FullText/Viana_Mon_May__7_17_52_39_EST_2001.html/wmy2000.pdf)
- *A. Pikovsky, M. Rosenblum*, [Dynamics of globally coupled oscillators: Progress and perspectives](http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/%7Emros/pdf/Chaos_25_review.pdf)
- *P. Holmes*, [Some Joys and Trials of Mathematical Neuroscience](https://www.princeton.edu/mae/people/faculty/holmes/recent_papers/H-MatNeu-JNS13epub.pdf)
- *B. Krauskopf, H. M. Osinga, E. J. Doedel, M. E. Henderson, J. Guckenheimer,

  A. Vladimirsky, M. Dellnitz, O. Junge*, [A survey of methods for computing (un)stable

  manifolds of vector fields](https://www-m3.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M3/Allgemeines/Kretal05/Kretal05-rev.pdf)
- *É. Ghys*, [Knots in dynamics](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_I/15.pdf)
- *A. J. Homburg, B. Sandstede*, [Homoclinic and Heteroclinic Bifurcations in Vector Fields](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/publications/survey-homoclinic-bifurcations.pdf)
- *D. Eroglu, J. Lamb, T. Pereira*, [Synchronization of Chaos](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08296.pdf)
- *J.-M. Ginoux, C. Letellier*, [Van der Pol and the history of relaxation
  oscillations: toward the emergence of a concept](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4890.pdf)
- *M. B. Sevryuk*, [The classical KAM theory at the dawn of the twenty-first century](http://www.ams.org/distribution/mmj/vol3-3-2003/sevryuk.pdf)
- *D. Aubin*, [Writing the History of Dynamical Systems and Chaos:
  Longue Duree and Revolution, Disciplines and Cultures](http://chaosbook.org/library/aubin-dahanPubl.pdf)
- *J. Chavarriga, M. Sabatini*, [A Survey of Isochronous Centers](http://www.ssd.udl.cat/abstracts/files/v11/SURV.pdf)
- *A. Champneys*, [A Twenty-First Century Guidebook for Applied Dynamical Systems](http://computationalnonlinear.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1394014)
- *C. Mira*, [Some Historical Aspects of Nonlinear Dynamics Possible Trends for the Future](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263571966_Some_Historical_Aspects_of_Nonlinear_Dynamics_Possible_Trends_for_the_Future)
- *M. Ghil, D. Sciamarella*, [Review Article: Dynamical Systems, Algebraic Topology, and the Climate Sciences](https://egusphere.copernicus.org/preprints/2023/egusphere-2023-216/egusphere-2023-216.pdf)

Comment: First link (Holmes) is dead. But this works instead: http://chaosbook.org/library/HolmesNonlHist05.pdf

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you very much for noticing that! I fixed the link :)

Comment: Hirsch's paper "The dynamical systems approach to differential equations" is also noteworthy in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Smale also wrote a little book *Mathematics of Time* which, as I recall, is also a pretty good survey.

Another favorite of mine is *Foundations of Mechanics* by Abraham and Marsden.

Comment: Aha, so Smale's "Differentiable dynamical systems" is a part of *Mathematics of time*? That's curious, hope that I'll find this book soon

Comment: @Evgeny:  I don't think *Mathematics of Time* includes all of *Differentiable Dynamical Systems*, but it might.  Pretty sure *MoT* has *some* of *DDS*, though.  It's a pretty cool little book, and inspired much of my early interest in dynamical systems.  Hope you find it!

Answer (score 2):

On ODEs and Chaos, I have the following recommendations:

1). This is a ~50 page document which describes some of the modern techniques of detecting chaos

http://docenti.lett.unisi.it/files/4/2/13/1/Wiggins_CHAOS.pdf

If this short document intrigues you, here are some detailed texts:

2). Global bifurcations and chaos: Wiggins

3). Chaos near resonance by G. Haller

The above two are monographs, and quite recent (by mathematical time scales).

4). Symplectic maps, variational principles, and transport
JD Meiss
Reviews of Modern Physics 64 (3), 795

Comment: I had a look at Wiggins and Meiss: Wiggins' book seems very comprehensive and Meiss seems to be a quite great dive in for symplectic science. Thank you!