# Good books in Dynamical systems!

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation

I'm looking for some good books or articles about dynamical systems with real variables. To be more specific, I'm looking for some material that explains about linear stability matrices and evolution matrices.

Obs: I'm new in this field, in this sense, something didatic would be very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=arnold+ordinary+differential+equations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFpfm4jdLRAhVLwiYKHaBNDaQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=arnold%20ordinary%20differential%20equations&f=false

Comment: [This](https://www.amazon.com/Nonlinear-Dynamics-Chaos-Applications-Nonlinearity/dp/0738204536) is a very good reference, very intuitive and clearly explained

Comment: Did you have a look at other posts tagged [dynamical-systems+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems+book-recommendation)? Perhaps looking at the ones tagged [dynamical-systems+reference-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamical-systems+reference-request) might be worth trying, too.

Comment: Although you are looking for books, [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf1264iFr-w&list=PLFEB6A8883C859AA4) is a great introduction to Linear Dynamical Systems(EE263 by S. Boyd). Materials are also available online, thus great for self study purposes.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510291/dynamical-systems-and-differential-equations-reviews-surveys) list might be useful. I've tried to collect interesting surveys and reviews. Although most of them are rather advanced, they might whet your appetite for studying this kind of math. Ashwin's review is especially interesting because it puts a lot of modern dynamical systems and nonlinear dynamics tools in the context of particular research.

Comment: I found [this one](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319068701) to be very useful. It almost perfectly fits your desired descriptions