# Why can I find Fixed points in a Dynamical System by Setting a map F(x) = x, and with a O.D.E by setting $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 0$, what is the connection?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

In elementary differential equations, one can find the fixed points of a single variable system by setting the derivative equal to zero and solving.

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \mu\,x - x^{3} = 0$$

In Dynamical systems and Chaos - there is a similar concept with regard to maps ...

$$ x_{n} = \mu\,x_{n+1} - x_{n}^{3} \rightarrow x_{n} - \mu x_{n+1} - x_{n}^{3} = 0$$

---

What is the connection between these two Ways of finding fixed points - and how would you convert from one to the other if possible?

This answer explores this question - but I'm not following the connection:
[Strange attractors: what is the difference between a map and differential equation system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477962/strange-attractors-what-is-the-difference-between-a-map-and-differential-equati)

Answer (score 0):

The connection is *constant solutions*. If in a discrete dynamic $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$ you get $x_n=c$ for all $n$, then obviously $c=g(c)$. In a continuous time dynamic $\dot x=f(x)$ the constant solutions $x(t)=c$ have derivative $\dot x=0$, so to satisfy the dynamic you need $f(c)=0$.

After that one starts to ask about stability. That is, starting close to a constant solution, does the dynamic lead further towards the constant solution or away from it.

Then there are periodic solutions that then have their own kinds of stability. If the dynamical system depends on a parameter, then usually such structures are generally stable towards small changes of the parameter, for example, if there is a periodic orbit, then with the changed parameter there will usually also be a periodic orbit close-by with a similar period. The interesting parameters are those where this breaks down, these are the bifurcation points (even for non-fork bifurcations).