# Computation of stable manifold

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems

I've been reading a bit around on computation of unstable manifold, which seem to be a big area of research, however no one ever mentions computation of the stable manifold.

Is this because you just reverse time, and then the stable manifold becomes the unstable one, thus computational methods of unstable manifolds also covers computation of stable ones?

Regards,

Comment: Yeah, even one of the most comprehensive surveys on this topic (see link in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510291/dynamical-systems-and-differential-equations-reviews-surveys)) "A survey of methods for computing (un)stable manifolds of vector fields" has this kind of word-play that suggests that these problems are to some extent the same. The caveat is only when an unstable manifold of transformed system escapes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stable manifolds are, well, stable under the phase-space flow. Thus, in the most simple case, all you need to do is to integrate forwards in time when you are in the vicinity and you’ll obtain the stable manifold. In some cases (e.g., a quasiperiodic attractor), things may be a bit more difficult, but the gist stays the same.

Comment: If you integrate trajectories in the vicinity of a saddle, after some time it traces out something very close to a part of unstable manifold :)